# Vuejs axios get comments to load more

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a controller on php, where I return all comments. I have a code:

```js
new Vue({
  el: ".vue",
  data() {
    return {
      reviews: [],
      commentsToShow: 2
    };
  },
  methods: {
      getComments() {
         axios.get('/api/comments').then(res => {
             this.reviews = res.data;
         });
      }
  }
  created() {
     this.getComments();  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container vue">
  <div v-if="commentIndex < reviews.length" v-for="commentIndex in commentsToShow"> 
    <div>{{reviews[commentIndex].name}} says:</div>
    <i><div>{{reviews[commentIndex].description}}</div></i>
    <hr />
  </div>
  <button @click="commentsToShow += 2">show more reviews</button>
</div>
```

How I can with axios get only 2 comments, but not all comments. And when click on the button load more comments... Now from axios I get all comments, this is not good for perfomance.

Comment: add `limit` param to your query and return from php-side only last `limit` comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement pagination. Pagination is server side, so you need to edit your controller. If you use Laravel, take a look at [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination). Else, you have to write your own paganiation, somithing like (just as an Idea)

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$perPage = 10;
$offset = $page*$perpage;

SELECT * FROM abc LIMIT $perpage OFFSET $offset
```

If you have your pagination working, you then simply would need to send the page you want together with your request:

```
axios.get('/api/comments', {
  params: {
    page: this.currentPage + 1
  }
}).then(res => {
  this.reviews = res.data;
  this.currentpage++;
});
```

this would return the results paginated.

**EDIT**

To use pagination in Laravel: You just have to change the ending of your Eloquent query, your Query should look someting like this:

```
$return = Comment::where('a', 1)->paginate(itemsPerPage); //use ->paginate()

return response()->json($return);
```

You are getting all information you need to work with, the axios request I've written before would work. You just have to define the page you want to get back. Just read the link to [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination), it's really good.

Comment: Can you please edit this for Laravel? I use Laravel project. Thanks.

Comment: `::where('a', 1)` What is this? `1` is limit?

Comment: this is just to build a query. Just a filter. If you want all your comments without filter, just call `Comment::paginate(itemsPerPage)`. If you want all published comments, use `Comment::where('published', 1)->paginate(itemsPerPage)` etc, I think you get the Idea

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!